# AJAX post receive strange text response

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I have 2 inputs `mkey` and `url`.
I'd like to change `key` when `url` changed by the following code:

```
const url = document.getElementById('url');
url.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    let url = event.target;
    let mkey = document.getElementById('mkey');

    $.post({
        url: "{{ route('contracts.regenerate') }}",
        data: {
            mkey: mkey.value,
            url: url.value,
        },
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        success: (data) => {
            alert(data);
            let mkey = document.getElementById('mkey');
            mkey.value = data;
        }
    });
});
```

Laval route with name `contracts.regenerate`:

```
 public function regenerateKey(Request $request) {
     $parts = explode('#', $request->mkey);
     $last = printf("%u", crc32($request->url));
     return $parts[0] . '#' . $last;
 }
```

The idea is to construct `mkey` as `original-mkey-before-hash#crc-from-url`.
Laravel back returns what I expect.
Example:

```
mkey.value = mkey_60501e2ae282a2.08095650
url.value = http://example.com
```

Laravel route returns string `mkey_60501e2ae282a2.08095650#123` (123 - sample).
That's right.

But `alert()` show me returned value `2797586643mkey_60501e2ae282a2.08095650#123`.
Digits **2797586643** before mkey are unexpected.

How to avoid these digits in response?

Comment: what is the output of this in your function `console.log(data);` instead of alert?

Comment: Look for those numbers in your PHP files `2797586643`. Check your config files first. if they are present before the `<?php` tag, they will be in every output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in usage of `printf` instead of required `sprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON for safe data transfers between back and frontend.

Change your controller\action to this:

```php
public function regenerateKey(Request $request) {
    $parts = explode('#', $request->mkey);
    $last = printf("%u", crc32($request->url));
    return response()->json([
        "mkey" => $parts[0] . '#' . $last
    ]);
}
```

also change your Js to:

```js
$.post({
    url: "{{ route('contracts.regenerate') }}",
    data: {
        mkey: mkey.value,
        url: url.value,
    },
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: (data) => {
        alert(data.mkey);
        let mkey = document.getElementById('mkey');
        mkey.value = data.mkey;
    }
});
```

Comment: Something wrong - `success` branch in JS don't reached

Comment: Change `success` to `complete` - reached. But the `data` value is `2797586643{"mkey":"mkey_60501e2ae282a2.08095650#10"}` - see unexpected digits before normal json

Comment: @ValeryBulash There must be a string added inside one of your code files. Do a project root level search with some IDE like vscode or phpstorm and look for **2797586643** and delete it.